# Check that your config file `flutter_launcher_icons.yaml` has a `flutter_icons` section

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image]

any one have solution to this problem i am running flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
and it is not working for me

Comment: In my case I didn't have a flutter_launcher_icons.yaml file at all. I had to manually create it and add the specific code inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your pubspec.yaml should be like this:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

> Notice where `flutter_launcher_icons` was used and where
> `flutter_icons` was used.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the same error you have, and it was something so simple that many of us do not realize it sometimes.

- Verify that the terminal is in your project folder.
- Try putting flutter_launcher_icons: any in the dev_dependencies: section like in the image.
- Verify correct indentation in pubspec.yaml

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrLSq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just ... Restart android studio

run

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
4. flutter run

Answer (score 0):

if you facing this problem

```
✗ ERROR: NoConfigFoundException
Check that your config file flutter_launcher_icons.yaml has a flutter_icons section
```

try this

1. uninstall the app from the phone or emulator
2. Go To Power Shell and run as Administrator
3. cd ( your project path )
4. `flutter pub get`
5. `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`
6. `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

if dependencies are upgraded degrade it to mentioned version
and use it.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"
```

```
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

and also change in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
```